# Node baseline in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, matrix, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
  \tikzset{graph/.style={matrix of nodes, inner sep=.25em, row sep= 1.5em,
      column sep= 6.25em}}
  \tikzset{mynode/.style={rectangle, anchor=center, minimum height=1.5em,
      font=\sffamily, text width=7.5em, align=center, draw}}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth]
    \matrix[graph]{
      |[mynode] (prev)| prev &
      |[mynode] (cur)| my node &
      |[mynode] (next)| next \\
    };
    \graph[use existing nodes, edges= rounded corners] {
      prev -> cur -> next;
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Three nodes with glyphs going below baseline]

"my node" and "next" are properly aligned, but if you check "prev", you'll see that the letter "p" is above the line.

How can I fix this? Please note that I may have nodes with more than one line of text, so it should be taken into account.

UPDATE 1:

The proposed fix by Ignasi works, but even after deleting the `text height` property, it seems to limit the node height to just one line worth of text. This breaks nodes who have multiple lines of text and are styled with `mynode` too:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}

%\usepackage{luatex85} %I'm using lualatex
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, matrix, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
  \tikzset{graph/.style={matrix of nodes, inner sep=.25em, row sep= 1.5em,
      column sep= 6.25em}}
  \tikzset{mynode/.style={rectangle, anchor=center, minimum height=1.5em, 
      font=\sffamily, text width=7.5em, text depth=.25ex, 
      align=center, draw}}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth]
    \matrix[graph]{
      |[mynode] (prev)| Look at this text. Lorem ipsum... &
      |[mynode] (cur)| Now look at this text. Lorem ipsum... &
      |[mynode] (next)| Finally, look at this text too. Lorem ipsum... \\
    };
    \graph[use existing nodes, edges= rounded corners] {
      prev -> cur -> next;
    };
    \draw[red] (cur.base-|prev.west)--(cur.base-|next.east);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Broken example]

Comment: `anchor=mid` ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You need to define `text height` and `text depth`**, as is explained in chapter 5 "Turorial: Diagrams as Simple Graphs" from `pgfmanual`. Especially § 5.1 states:

> The nodes suddenly “dance around”! There is no hope of changing the
>   position of text inside a node using anchors. Instead, Ilka must use a
>   trick: The problem of mismatching baselines is caused by the fact that
>   . and digit and E all have different heights and depth. If they all
>   had the same, they would all be positioned vertically in the same
>   manner. So, all Ilka needs to do is to use the text height and text
>   depth options to explicitly specify a height and depth for the nodes

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, matrix, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
  \tikzset{graph/.style={matrix of nodes, inner sep=.25em, row sep= 1.5em,
      column sep= 1.5em, column sep= 6.25em}}
  \tikzset{mynode/.style={rectangle, anchor=center, minimum height=1.5em, 
      font=\sffamily, text width=7.5em,text height=1.5ex, text depth=.25ex, align=center, draw}}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth]
    \matrix[graph]{
      |[mynode] (prev)| prev &
      |[mynode] (cur)| my node &
      |[mynode] (next)| next \\
    };
    \graph[use existing nodes, edges= rounded corners] {
      prev -> cur -> next;
    };
%    \draw[red] (cur.base-|prev.west)--(cur.base-|next.east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works, but only for single line nodes. If one sets `text depth` and `text width`, the node will not stretch beyond `minimum width` and the text will overflow the node.

Comment: @amyspark As I'm not sure about the meaning of your comment, please update the question with a `non working` example and what you would like to obtain in this case.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'll update it now.

Comment: @Ignasi, to me is not clear, where should be baseline (at the first line?), does the nodes heights can be different etc. Demands in question are contradictory.

Comment: I wanted not to style nodes depending on whether they have one or more lines of text (see the non-working example above wrt`text depth`).

Answer (score 6):

Did you try `anchor=mid` as I suggested yesterday? Did you try looking it up to find out what it does?

Presumably not ...

```
  mynode/.style={rectangle, anchor=mid, text height=1em, font=\sffamily, text width=7.5em, align=center, draw},
```

gives me

[image: aligned to <code>.mid</code> anchor]

Now, clearly, you cannot have your cake and eat it. If you align the nodes with `.mid` then they will be aligned on the baseline. Well and good. Then you have three choices. You could use `text depth` to fix a larger depth, but this will result in one-liners looking really silly.

[image: fixed depth]

Or you could tolerate the arrows between the nodes not going due East.

[image: angled arrows]

Or you can specify the anchors for the arrows so that these are also aligned relative to `.mid`, which is the solution shown above and demonstrated below. This seemed to me the only workable solution and it permits easy customisation for particular cases when required.

I also set the `text height` to avoid small variations in the vertical location of the north borders of the nodes. Just remove it if you prefer not to use it.

Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, matrix, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
  my graph/.style={matrix of nodes, inner sep=.25em, row sep= 1.5em, column sep= 6.25em},
  mynode/.style={rectangle, anchor=mid, text height=1em, font=\sffamily, text width=7.5em, align=center, draw},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth]
  \matrix[my graph]{
    |[mynode] (prev)| prev &
    |[mynode] (cur)| my node &
    |[mynode] (next)| next \\
  };
  \graph[use existing nodes, edges= rounded corners] {
    prev.mid east -> cur.mid west ; cur.mid east -> next.mid west;
  };
  \draw[red] (cur.base-|prev.west)--(cur.base-|next.east);
  \begin{scope}[yshift=-20mm]
    \matrix[my graph]{
      |[mynode] (prev)| Look at this text. Lorem ipsum... &
      |[mynode] (cur)| Now look at this text. Lorem ipsum... &
      |[mynode] (next)| Finally, look at this text too. Lorem ipsum... \\
    };
    \graph[use existing nodes, edges= rounded corners] {
      prev.mid east -> cur.mid west ; cur.mid east -> next.mid west;
    };
    \draw[red] (cur.base-|prev.west)--(cur.base-|next.east);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```