# Modify Timeline

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, timeline, moderntimeline, chronosys

How to modify this timeline (as shown in the attached image):

1. Have a dashed arrow coming out of the rectangular see ([Timeline in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436259/timeline-in-latex)).
2. Remove the left and right borders.
3. Relocate the names of A123 and X256 to be inside the rectangle

[image]

```
        \documentclass[10pt]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{chronosys}
    \usepackage[paperwidth=34cm, paperheight=10cm]{geometry}%taille du document
    
    \definecolor{gry}{HTML}{375D81}
    \definecolor{cyan}{HTML}{00ffff}
    
    
    \begin{document}
        %---------------------timeline----------------%
        \startchronology[align=left, startyear=1993,stopyear=2037, height=0pt, startdate=false, stopdate=false, dateselevation=0pt, arrow=false, box=true]
        %
        \chronograduation[event][dateselevation=0pt]{1}
        %---------------------periods----------------%
        \chronoperiode[textstyle=\colorbox{gry!50}, color=gry, startdate=false, bottomdepth=0pt, topheight=15pt, textdepth=35pt,dateselevation=12pt, stopdate=false]{1994}{2020}{X256}
        
        \chronoperiode[textstyle=\colorbox{cyan!50}, color=cyan, startdate=false, bottomdepth=16pt, topheight=31pt, textdepth=-25pt, dateselevation=12pt, stopdate=false]{1998}{2019}{A123}
        
    
        \stopchronology
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you want chronosys as compared to Tikz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do it with plain-`Tikz`, as `chronosys` hides Tikz effectively. A few remarks:

1. I switched to the `standalone` class to get rid of paper format problems.
2. The styles defined are for bluebar, graybar, arrow tipp and arr-appearance.
3. The bars are simply thick lines, where I remember the coordinates at the end `BB`, `GB`
4. The time line is just a line, plus a loop to place the text. I assume a 1cm grid for simplicity.
5. Recalling coordinates `BB` and `GB` the additional arrows are easy to draw, stretching 10 units (cm) to the right. Adjust dashes like shown in the [pgfmanual](https://tikz.dev/tikz-actions#sec-15.3.2).
6. Labels are easy to place. As you can seem I cild have calculated the required `cm` by a simple difference, too.
7. If you want to scale this picture later, don't forget to include `transform shape` in the options, see [pgfmanual](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.7).

[image: result]

```
%\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
%%%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{chronosys}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
%\usepackage[paperwidth=34cm, paperheight=10cm]{geometry}%taille du document
    
\definecolor{gry}{HTML}{375D81}
\definecolor{cyan}{HTML}{00ffff}
    

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    bb/.style={line width=1cm, draw=cyan},
    gb/.style={line width=1cm, draw=gry},
    >={Latex},
    arr/.style={->,dashed,red},
 ]
    % ~~~ bars ~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[bb] (5,1.5) -- (25,1.5) coordinate (BB);
    \draw[gb] (1,0.5) -- (26,0.5) coordinate (GB);
    
    % ~~~ time line ~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw (0,0) -- (44,0);
    \foreach \yr [count=\i] in {1994,1995,...,2037}
        \draw (\i,0) -- +(0,-.8) node[fill=white] {\yr};
        
    % ~~~ additional arrows ----
    \draw[arr] (BB) -- +(10,0);
    \draw[arr] (GB) -- +(10,0);
    
    % ~~~ labels ~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node             at (2006-1993,1.5) {A123};
    \node[text=white] at (2004-1993,0.5) {X256};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```