# Set label anchor within node style definition

Tags: tikz-pgf, alignment

I am trying to set `anchor=base` for my node labels so that the labels are aligned at their baselines. It seems to work if I set the option in the label itself, but not if I set the option globally.

**With no options:**

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone} 

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{mynode/.style={circle,fill=black}}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \draw  (0,0) node[mynode,label={Aa}] (n1) {}
            -- (1,0) node[mynode,label={Ag}] (n2) {}
            -- (2,0) node[mynode,label={Bb}] (n3) {};           

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**With options set in each label:**

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone} 

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{mynode/.style={circle,fill=black}}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \draw  (0,0) node[mynode,label={[anchor=base,yshift=2pt]Aa}] (n1) {}
            -- (1,0) node[mynode,label={[anchor=base,yshift=2pt]Ag}] (n2) {}
            -- (2,0) node[mynode,label={[anchor=base,yshift=2pt]Bb}] (n3) {};           

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**With options set globally:**

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone} 

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{mynode/.style={circle,fill=black}}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[every label/.style={anchor=base,yshift=2pt}]

        \draw  (0,0) node[mynode,label={Aa}] (n1) {}
            -- (1,0) node[mynode,label={Ag}] (n2) {}
            -- (2,0) node[mynode,label={Bb}] (n3) {};           

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But setting other options globally seems to work; for example, if I change to

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every label/.style={blue,anchor=base,yshift=2pt}]
```

then I get:

[image]

*How can I set the alignment globally instead of in each label individually?* (Even better would be if I can set the label style within the node style declaration.)

Comment: You  could just use a matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referencing [Node baseline in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315075/node-baseline-in-tikz) and *Section 5.1
Styling the Nodes* of the `pgf manual`:

> The problem of mismatching baselines is caused by the fact
>   that . and digit and E all have different heights and depth. If they all had the same, they would all be
>   positioned vertically in the same manner. So, all Ilka needs to do is to use the text height and text depth
>   options to explicitly specify a height and depth for the nodes.

So, if we use, for example

```
every label/.append style={text depth=.25ex,color=blue,},
```

then we obtain

[image]

Here's a complete example

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{mynode/.append style={circle,fill=black},
    every label/.append style={text depth=.25ex,color=blue,},
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw  (0,0) node[mynode,label={Aa}] (n1) {}
    -- (1,0) node[mynode,label={Ag}] (n2) {}
    -- (2,0) node[mynode,label={Bb}] (n3) {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the anchor gets overwritten. In other words, `every label` gets applied too early. As a workaround, I added a second version of `every label`, `every label add`, which gets applied later. If you then say

```
every label add/.style={anchor=base}
```

the anchor will be set as desired.

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter% from tikz.code.tex
\def\tikz@@parse@label@nonactive[#1]#2:#3:\pgf@nil{%
  \tikzset{%
    append after command = {%
      \bgroup
        [current point is local=true]
        \pgfextra{\let\tikz@save@last@fig@name=\tikz@last@fig@name\tikz@node@is@a@labelfalse}
        node [every label,
              tikz@label@angle = #2,
              anchor=@auto,
              every label add,%<- added
              #1,
              tikz@label@post = \tikz@label@distance] {\iftikz@handle@active@nodes\expandafter\scantokens\else\expandafter\pgfutil@firstofone\fi{#3\noexpand}}
        \pgfextra{\global\let\tikz@last@fig@name=\tikz@save@last@fig@name}
      \egroup}}}%
\tikzset{every label add/.style={}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tikzset{mynode/.style={circle,fill=black}}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \draw  (0,0) node[mynode,label={[anchor=base,yshift=2pt]Aa}] (n1) {}
            -- (1,0) node[mynode,label={[anchor=base,yshift=2pt]Ag}] (n2) {}
            -- (2,0) node[mynode,label={[anchor=base,yshift=2pt]Bb}] (n3) {};           

    \end{tikzpicture}


    \begin{tikzpicture}[every
    label/.append style={yshift=2pt},every label add/.style={anchor=base}]

        \draw  (0,0) node[mynode,label={Aa}] (n1) {}
            -- (1,0) node[mynode,label={Ag}] (n2) {}
            -- (2,0) node[mynode,label={Bb}] (n3) {};           

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It may conceivably make sense to make a feature request for something of that sort.

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 As I said, I think you have found a real issue, and debugging it was fun but also some amount of work. IMHO the other answer does not answer the question why the anchor gets ignored at all.

Comment: That's true, but it's an easier workaround for me, hence the checkmark. However, I do appreciate your debugging, and I will make a feature request to fix this. Do you know what's the best way to go about doing that?

Comment: @Schrodingerscat Done.